# C++ basic calculator. Beginner

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain to me where is the error in my code?
It is a simple calculator. The end result is nonsense numbers for some reason and when it compiles it doesn't even consider going trough "izteiksmju kalkulators". Thank you very much for help!

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {

     string o,funkcija;
     double x,y,l,result;
     double Pi = 3.14159265359;
     char operators;
     cout << "Velaties izmantot aritmetikas vai funkciju kalkulatoru?" << endl;
     getline(cin,o);

     if (o == "funkciju kalkulators" || "funkciju" || "oo")
     {
        cout << "ievadiet funkciju:" << endl;
        cin >> l;
        if (funkcija == "cos")  result = (x*Pi/180);
        if (funkcija == "sin")  result = (x*Pi/180);
        if (funkcija == "tan")  result = (x*Pi/180);
        if (funkcija == "exp")  result = exp(x);
        if (funkcija == "log")  result = log(x); 
        if (funkcija == "sqrt") result = sqrt(x);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " " << result;
    }

    else if (o == "Izteiksmju kalkulators" || "izteiksmi" || "aa")
    {
        cout << "Ievadiet izteiksmi:" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> operators;
        cin >> y;
        if (operators == '+')  result = x+y;
        if (operators == '-')  result = x-y;
        if (operators == '*')  result = x*y;
        if (operators == '/')  result = x/y;
        cout << "Rezultats:" << " " << result << endl;
   }

   else
   {
        cout << "error" << endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (o == "funkciju kalkulators" || "funkciju" || "oo")` That's always true.

Comment: I didn't realise cos, sin and tan were so similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comparison

```
o == "Izteiksmju kalkulators" || "izteiksmi" || "aa"
```

Doesn't mean what you think, it will evaluate the booleanness of the later strings and the whole thing is always true, instead you probable mean

```
o == "Izteiksmju kalkulators" || o == "izteiksmi" || o == "aa"
```

the same goes for your similar `if` expressions

Answer (score 2):

Here was there many errors.

```
if (o == "funkciju kalkulators" || "funkciju" || "oo")
```

What is this? This will in all cases be `true`, it should be written like this:

```
if (o == "funkciju kalkulators" || o == "funkciju" || o == "oo")
```

And same with:

```
else if (o == "Izteiksmju kalkulators" || "izteiksmi" || "aa")
```

Should be:

```
else if (o == "Izteiksmju kalkulators" || o == "izteiksmi" || o == "aa")
```

---

```
if (funkcija == "cos")  result = (x*Pi/180);
if (funkcija == "sin")  result = (x*Pi/180);
if (funkcija == "tan")  result = (x*Pi/180);
if (funkcija == "exp")  result = exp(x);
if (funkcija == "log")  result = log(x); 
if (funkcija == "sqrt") result = sqrt(x);
```

Where is `funkcija` and `x` initialized?

---

And where is `l` used?

```
cin >> l;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know how to intialize. I searched in google and relaised that I just dont understand what it means in english.

Comment: It's mean to assign a value to the variable for first time. You can do it like this `funkcija = 0;` or by reading from user by `cin >> funkcija`.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to forgot to initialize  x,y,l,result
till you do, they are garbage.
so, result = sqrt(x) when x is garbage... will give you garbage.

also, when you use || you need to write the entire condition for all three statements.